# PHP Google Cloud Translate not working with Korean

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-translation-api

I have a PHP script that is translating user responses to map data to pre-defined categories. It currently works for translating Spanish responses (es) to English (en) but when I try to pass Korean (ko) text through the Google Cloud Translate service seems to be receiving incorrect source text and therefore not translating correctly.

I have tried looking into the encoding but everything is currently set to UTF8. I'm also outputting the text before it gets set to make sure that the script is getting the correct text.

```php
$translate = new TranslateClient();

$options = array( 'target' => 'en', 'format' => 'text' );
$text = "토요일 맡긴 짐이 월요일 발송됨";

$result = $translate->translate( $text, $options );
```

Expected result:

```
Array(
    [source] => ko
    [input] => 토요일 맡긴 짐이 월요일 발송됨
    [text] => The baggage for Saturday is shipped on Monday
)
```

Actual result:

```
Array (
    [source] => is
    [input] => íìì¼ ë§¡ê¸´ ì§ì´ ììì¼ ë°ì¡ë¨
    [text] => â † † â † â † â † â † â † â †
)
```

Comment: I don't want to be stubborn, but this still looks like an encoding issue to me.

Comment: I agree that it looks like an encoding issue...I just can't seem to figure out how to encode/decode the response. The `TranslateClient` class doesn't seem to have any options for setting the encoding and if I encode the text prior to running the `translate` function, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Run `var_dump(bin2hex($text));` and paste the output so we can what exact bytes you're using.

Comment: `string(86) "ed86a0ec9a94ec9dbc20eba7a1eab8b420eca790ec9db420ec9b94ec9a94ec9dbc20ebb09cec86a1eb90a8"`